# What's the easiest way to list out the open windows in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I know I could've been searching on Google, but I've been rusty at it to the point where I'm not sure what terms I should search for. It would help to hear your suggestions here.

Example:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Windows("FL_bounces.csv").Activate
    Windows("auto_dealers_FL.csv").Activate
    Windows("FL_bounces.csv").Activate
    Windows("auto_dealers_FL.csv").Activate
End Sub
```

Except where I don't know the names of the windows open.

Edit #2:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim wn, contacts, report As Excel.Window
    Dim windows(1 To 100) As Excel.Window
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    For Each wn In Application.windows
        windows(i) = wn
        i = i + 1
    Next wn

    If IsEmailValid(windows(1).Cells(1, 1)) = True Then
        report = windows(1)
        contacts = windows(2)
    Else
        contacts = windows(1)
        report = windows(2)
    End If


End Sub
```

What do you see wrong in this modification?

Comment: How about `list` `window` `excel` `vba` `enumerate`? Oh, sorry, I thought you were just after the search terms :-)

Comment: I know it has to do with `window` and maybe `list`.

Comment: Do you mean list of open workbooks ?

Comment: @user2063626: See the edits.

Comment: Well, I think I answered your original question, i.e., "how to list open windows," but you need to explain what you are trying to do with this "report" and "contacts" stuff.

Comment: I'm trying to parse through one Excel spreadsheet with the email addresses in the first column, and then go to the other open Excel window, find each email address, and then delete the row containing the email address.

Comment: You don't need the `Window` object to do that. You need the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects.

Answer (score 3):

This will list all the currently open windows in the Immediate Pane:

```
Sub ListWindows()
Dim wn As Excel.Window
For Each wn In Application.Windows
    Debug.Print wn.Caption
Next wn
End Sub
```

Or, if you want to activate them, as in your sample code

```
Sub ActivateWindows()
Dim wn As Excel.Window
For Each wn In Application.Windows
    wn.Activate
    MsgBox wn.Caption & " Window Activated"
Next wn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try AutoIT. You need reference to AutoIT dll.
Here is link from where you can download autoit dll http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

The variant datatype in AutoIt natively supports window handles (HWNDs). A window handle is a special value that windows assigns to a window each time it is created. When you have a handle you may use it in place of the title parameter in any of the function calls that use the title/text convention. The advantage of using window handles is that if you have multiple copies of an application open - which have the same title/text - you can uniquely identify them when using handles. When you use a window handle for the title parameter then the text parameter is completely ignored.

Various functions such as WinGetHandle, WinList and GUICreate return these handles. It is important to note that a window handle is not classed as a number or string - it is its own special type.

```
Public Sub TestingAutoIT()
    Dim autoItObj As AutoItX3
    Set autoItObj = New AutoItX3

    With autoItObj    
        .WinActivate ("A Window Name")        
    End With

    Set autoItObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a solution [posted by VBA Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=52).  It will list all the open windows on the activesheet.

Note that "a window" is not necessarily what the user normally thinks of... some windows are collections of many windows, the way Windows sees it.